# CMake converts explicit Boost library path to -lboost_program_options, but linker finds wrong library

Tags: boost, cmake

I'm using CMake to compile a C++ program that uses `boost::program_options`. I've forced CMake to find the correct headers and libraries by running CMake as follows

```
cmake \
-DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME=/path/to/correct/boost/ \
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/path/to/correct/boost/lib/ \
-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/path/to/correct/boost/include/ \
-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=BOOL:ON \
.
```

CMake reports that it finds the `boost` library I wanted it to find:

```
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   program_options
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /path/to/correct/boost/include
-- Boost_LIBRARIES: /path/to/correct/boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so
```

I then call `make VERBOSE=1 -j`.

However, CMake sets up the Makefile so that instead of passing

```
-L/path/to/correct/boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so
```

to `gcc`, it passes

```
-lboost_program_options
```

The linker then fails to find the correct library, because it appends `../lib64/` to the directory:

```
attempt to open /path/to/correct/boost/lib/../lib64/libboost_program_options.so failed
```

`gcc` then attempts to link against the wrong version of boost:

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib64/libboost_program_options.so succeeded
-lboost_program_options (/usr/lib/../lib64/libboost_program_options.so)
```

This leads to `undefined reference` errors, as one would expect with the wrong library version.

How can I force `gcc` to use the exact library path that CMake found (`Boost_LIBRARIES`)? Is there a way to prevent CMake from converting the explicit library path to `-lboost_program_options`? Alternatively, is there a way to get the linker to look in the correct directory, with `lib/` in the path instead of `lib64/`?

Comment: What version of CMake and Boost?

Comment: CMake 3.9.4, and Boost 1.63.0.

Comment: Ok, your Cmake is recent enough.

Comment: How does your `target_link_libraries` look like? It should be something like `target_link_libraries(myTarget Boost::program_options)`

Comment: @oLen It looks like this: `target_link_libraries(target ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`. It's preceded by `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)` and
`include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. I've verified that `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you with Boost 1.65.1 and CMake 3.9.3.
But I was lucky, I had one project that didn't work, and another that did, with the same tools and libraries on the same machine.

The project that didn't work had this at the beginning of the top level CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
```

However, the good project has

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
```

That actually changes how cmake behaves.

Comment: What the <insert-expletive-of-your-choice-here>, just ran into this issue and bumping up the cmake_minimum_required version indeed fixes the issue. Otherwise, cmake simply insists on replacing all references to absolute paths of boost shared libraries to their -lboost equivalent.